# Laravel seed inserta datos de más

Tags: laravel, factory, seed

Al correr este código `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` el factory me inserta más datos de los que necesito. Por ejemplo me genera 35 status en total, y yo solamente requiero de 5, ¿por qué solamente 5? pues por este método que tengo en mi modelo de Idea:

```
    public function getStatusClasses()
    { 
        $allStatuses = [
            'Open' => 'bg-gray-200 text-gray-900',
            'Considering' => 'bg-purple text-white w-32',
            'In Progress' => 'bg-yellow text-gray-900 h-10',
            'Implemented' => 'bg-green text-white w-32',
            'Closed' => 'bg-red text-white',
        ];

        return $allStatuses[$this->status->name];
    }
```

Al final me genera 35 y al no poder identificar los nombres de los otros 30 datos me sale este mensaje de error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined index: quod nam (View: /Users/$USER/proyectos/miproyecto/resources/views/idea/index.blade.php)
```

También se generan 34 categorías diferentes y tampoco quiero ni voy a necesitar esa cantidad, sólamente 4 que son las que indico en mi DatabaseSeeder.

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
    public function run()
    {
        Status::factory()->create(['name' => 'Closed']);
        Status::factory()->create(['name' => 'Open']);
        Status::factory()->create(['name' => 'Considering']);
        Status::factory()->create(['name' => 'In Progress']);
        Status::factory()->create(['name' => 'Implemented']);
        
        Category::factory()->create(['name' => 'Category 1']);
        Category::factory()->create(['name' => 'Category 2']);
        Category::factory()->create(['name' => 'Category 3']);
        Category::factory()->create(['name' => 'Category 4']);

        Idea::factory(30)->create();
    }
```

**IdeaFactory.php**

Así estoy insertando los datos desde mi factory, los vinculos ya están en el modelo de Idea.

La relación es algo así: que 1 usuario puede tener muchas ideas, esa idea puede tener 1 categoría asignada y a la vez un sólo status.

```
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'user_id' => User::factory(),
            'status_id' => Status::factory(),
            'category_id' => Category::factory(),
            'title' => ucwords($this->faker->words(4, true)),
            'description' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
        ];
    }
```

Así es como tengo el blade, usando ese método dentro del div:

```
<div class="{{ $idea->getStatusClasses() }} cursor-pointer text-xs font-bold uppercase leading-none rounded-full text-center w-28 h-7 py-2 px-4">
 {{ $idea->status->name }}
</div>
```

Entonces el problema está en que al no poder encontrar "quod nam", por ejemplo, ya que así se llama uno de los datos generados al azar por el faker, pues surge el error que no puede encontrar ese index.

El otro problema está en que me genera 34 categorías y yo sólamente quiero 4.

Me gustaría poder insertar un total de 30 ideas, 4 categorías y 5 status, ¿cómo le tengo que hacer?

Gracias :-)

Comment: Y como le hago para que seleccione al menos una de las 4 categorías y 1 status al azar? Para que vaya recorriendo entre las diferentes opciones de esas 2 tablas y así poder ver resultados variados

Comment: Asi: ```'status_id' => Status::factory()->inRandomOrder()->first(),
'category_id' => Category::factory()->inRandomOrder()->first(),```  ?

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado, era literalmente como lo escribiste, te agradezco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces

```
Idea::factory(30)->create();
```

va a crear 30 registros del modelo `Idea`. Y por cada uno, un registro de `Status` y otro de `Category`.

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => User::factory(),
        'status_id' => Status::factory(), // crea un nuevo registro de Status
        'category_id' => Category::factory(), // crea un nuevo registro de Category
        'title' => ucwords($this->faker->words(4, true)),
        'description' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
    ];
}
```

Tendrías que seleccionar un `Status` y una `Category` existente en vez de crear nuevos.

Para ello, puedes consultar en la BD, por ejemplo, seleccionando un registro al azar de esos modelos.

Así obtienes un registro al azar:

```
Status::inRandomOrder()->first();
Category::inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Entonces en el factory del modelo `Idea`, puedes hacer la definición de esta manera:

```
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'user_id' => User::factory(),
        'status_id' => Status::inRandomOrder()->first(), // selecciona un Status existente al azar
        'category_id' => Category::inRandomOrder()->first(), // selecciona un Category existente al azar
        'title' => ucwords($this->faker->words(4, true)),
        'description' => $this->faker->paragraph(5),
    ];
}
```